# Where to see the process of ArangoDB pregel loading?

Tags: arangodb, pregel

When I start a pregel execution for a large graph, i still get a "loading" status from "pregel.status()" function after few days.

```
127.0.0.1:8529@pagerank> pregel.status()
[ 
  { 
    "id" : "11866", 
    "algorithm" : "pagerank", 
    "created" : "2023-11-20T07:58:16Z", 
    "ttl" : 600, 
    "state" : "loading", 
    "gss" : 0, 
    "graphLoaded" : false, 
    "user" : "root" 
  } 
]
```

How can i enable to see how many documents of graph have been loaded by pregel execution?